# Why shouldn't the black king move to h7?

Tags: puzzles

If white plays ne6+, why shouldn't black play kh7?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1...Kh7 leads to 2. Qxh6+! Kxh6 3. Rh3+ with mate in 2. If 2...Kg8, Black is mated with 3. Qxg6 Kh8 4. Rh1 with mate in 2.

Comment: I missed a very similar combination on one of my first tournament games.

Comment: Did someone make a bunch of comments and delete them? :D Great answer, my gut intuition was not to use the Queen for Qxh6 because you lose the Queen but it's actually a useful strategic move. I've only been playing for less than a week (used to play casually when I was 10 with my Grandad and haven't played for nearly 22 years). Recently realized it's a great game; funny enough thanks to the Warhammer Regicide release.